# Why do some turbofan blade have forward swept tips?

Tags: turbofan

I notice that in Trent700  engine fan blade there is no curve extension at the tip unlike in other engine's fan blades such as the GE90 ,T900 etc.

What are the purpose of it?

---

[image]

Trent 700 without forward swept blade tips

---

[image]

Engine with forward swept blade tips

Comment: These two images look to be exactly the same?

Comment: Do you mean the tips of the blades are swept forward in some parts of some engines but not others and you want to know why it's done?

Comment: This may be about the absence of mid-span [snubber](http://s184.photobucket.com/user/kach22i/media/FAN-2.jpg.html).

Comment: Hello Ajas, welcome to Aviation.SE. I have edited your question by including the Trent 700 image from your duplicate question and clarifying the question. I hope it now reflect what you wanted to ask. Please don't post duplicate question, instead use the <edit> link below your questions to make clarifications if needed. Could you also add the photo source and credit the photographer below each image?

Comment: I have another question: why are the tips here forward swept, but not swept backwards like the  wing? What are the differences in aerodynamic properties?

Answer (score 9):

Increasing performance of the fan means making it rotate faster. Tips of the fast-rotating fan travel at supersonic speeds. This design of fan blades is to overcome blade stall and to increase effectiveness of the fan. The design is probably patented and that's why it doesn't show up on engines of other manufacturers.

Comment: Here is a related patent:  https://www.google.com/patents/US6071077